# Java / VMWare - Interactions between vim and vim25

Tags: java, vmware

I'm trying to use a ManagedObjectRefence obtained from AppUtils.vim.VMUtils as an object in a tool from the vim25 library.

I am getting an error saying that a vim ManagedObjectReference is not compatible with a vim25 ManagedObjectReference. There does not seem to be a VMUtils tool in the vim25 library.

I have found a class at http://vlab-vwa.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/backend/apputils/vim25/VMUtils.java which claims to be a vim25 version of VMUtils, but it uses the vim ManagedObjectReference which again is not compatible with vim25, so the class is full of errors when it comes to compile-time.

Is there a way to interact between vim and vim25, or an equivalent of VMUtils for vim25?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with the libraries you are using, but I can speak to the API side.

To the VMware API (on ESX/vCenter), a managed object reference is just a pair of strings: a type, and an identifier. (See [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vi3/sdk/ReferenceGuide/vmodl.ManagedObjectReference.html).)

If the com.vmware.vim.ManagedObjectReference type from VMUtils will give you access to the type and value fields, you should be able to construct an equivalent object in vim25.

Alternatively, if you could clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish, perhaps there's a better answer out there.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, I do believe you want to use `ServiceInstance` to accomplish what you would in C# with `VMUtils.cs` (vim25 C# version), or in `VMUtils.java` (vim Java version).  I'm not sure what the full story is with VMUtils.java, but it appears it is now deprecated/not included.

**Interaction with vim:**

The visdk4.0 , or "vim" version shows the following method signatures for VMUtils.java:

```
 browseArrayList
 browseMOR
 createVirtualDisk
 createVmConfigSpec         
 getConfigTargetForHost
 getDefaultDevicescomputeResMor
 getHost
 getHostFolder
 getVMs
```

Look here for corresponding JavaDoc:
http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/samples/javadoc/com/vmware/apputils/vim/VMUtils.html

**Interaction with vim25:**

The aforementioned methods or their equivalents are available in the vim25 version if you start with a `ServiceInstance` object and drill down from there.  See the reference documentation: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50/PG_Ch2_Programming_Model.4.4.html#1040021

**Further resources:**

I highly recommend taking a good look at the "VI Java API" as an alternative and complimentary solution to using the raw vSphere Web Services SDK.
The project can be found here: http://vijava.sourceforge.net/ and here: http://www.doublecloud.org/